# Splitting values into separate cells

Tags: python, pandas, text

While I am importing the text file, all the variables are falling under single column. I want the values and columns in separate cells

Appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: you have used tab as delimiter but by looking at output, it doesn't seem like a tab delimited file but rather a space delimited file. Can you try using ```delimiter=' '```

Comment: I tried it, it throws an error "ValueError: only single character unicode strings can be converted to Py_UCS4, got length 0"

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by using delim_whitespace